# Use integer keys in Berkeley DB with python (using bsddb3)

Tags: python, berkeley-db, bsddb

I want to use BDB as a time-series data store, and planning to use the microseconds since epoch as the key values. I am using BTREE as the data store type.

However, when I try to store integer keys, bsddb3 gives an error saying `TypeError: Integer keys only allowed for Recno and Queue DB's`.

What is the best workaround? I can store them as strings, but that probably will make it unnecessarily slower.

Given BDB itself can handle any kind of data, why is there a restriction? can I sorta hack the bsddb3 implementation? has anyone used anyother methods?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, there's no workaround. But you can use two approaches

1. Store the integers as string using `str` or `repr`. If the ints are big, you can even use string formatting
2. use cPickle/pickle module to store and retrieve data. This is a good way if you have data types other than basic types. For basics `int`s and `float`s this actually is slower and takes more space than just storing strings

Answer (score 1):

You can't store integers since bsddb doesn't know how to represent integers and which kind of integer it is.

If you convert your integer to a string you will break the lexicographic ordering of keys of bsddb: `10 > 2` but as strings `"10" < "2"`.

You have to use python [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to convert your integers into a string (or in python 3 into bytes) to store then store them in bsddb. You have to use bigendian packing or ordering will not be correct.

Then you can use bsddb's `Cursor.set_range(key)` to query for information in a given slice of time.

For instance, `Cursor.set_range(struct.unpack('>Q', 123456789))` will set the cursor at the key of the even happening at 123456789 or the first that happens after.