# Implementing a basic graph database engine

Tags: graph-databases

I need to implement a simple graph database engine, what are the things should I consider? First, I am confused between which data structure to use, I mean graph representation (like adjacency matrix or adjacency list) or the actual graph itself? I need this to be scalable. 
Later how do I store the graph in the hard disk as files? After I store the graph data in the form of files, I would also need a way to selectively load only certain files into the graph, since I can not load everything at once into the RAM. Sorry for being vague, but I need someone to point me in the right direction. Also please suggest the language I can use, can I use python for this project? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use an existing graph database like neo?

Comment: because it defeats the purpose of the project? I'm talking about creating something like neo4j, but a much simpler version, not using it...

Comment: I created such a database in Python already there's several implementations have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ajgu https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AjguDB and also this post http://hypermove.net/notes/do-it-yourself-a-graph-database-in-python/

Comment: the basic is that you need to use key/value like leveldb (but it's slow) and build upon it the graph datastructure. You can go with a documentat store too, but usually they don't provide good ACID semantic.

Comment: @adityasista can you mark or at least upvote my answer if it answer your question? Thanks.

Comment: @amirouche: I did, my reputation is too low for that to appear publicly...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs you will implement different interface to the database ie. an adjacency matrix or the graph itself.

Instead of using a file based database, the important step forward you can take is use a key/value store like [bsddb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bsddb), [leveldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leveldb) or [wiredtiger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wiredtiger) (prefered). This will deal with caching often accessed files, provide ACID semantic, and indices if you use wiredtiger.

The storage layer made upon the key/value store, can have several layout. It depends on the final interface you need.

To get started with developing custom databases using key/value stores I recommend you read questions answered about mostly leveldb and bsddb on SO.

Like the following:

- [store list in key value database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513419/store-list-in-key-value-database)
- [How to give multiple values to a single key using a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873620/how-to-give-multiple-values-to-a-single-key-using-a-dictionary/32147466#32147466)
- [Use integer keys in Berkeley DB with python (using bsddb3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664940/use-integer-keys-in-berkeley-db-with-python-using-bsddb3/32147596#32147596)
- [Expressing multiple columns in berkeley db in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399643/expressing-multiple-columns-in-berkeley-db-in-python)